# Scraping certain text from a web page using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am downloading some data to help improve my Spanish. On this webpage I am able to download the table of conjugations, however I can't seem to get the English translation & the box beneath it.

At the top of the page their is a Spanish flag & to the right of it is a Union Jack flag, I'm trying to get that text which is "laugh; smile; giggle;..."

Beneath, there's a box, which has the following values I'm also trying to get,

> Infinitivo reír    Gerundo riendo   Participio Pasado reído

The code I have used to get the other tables is below. I'm not sure how to find the other elements mentioned above?

```
URL = 'https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-spanish-verb-reír.html'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='ch_divSimple')

verb_tbls = results.find_all('ul', class_='wrap-verbs-listing')
```

Comment: You wrote Spanish but your URL is for Portugese, in which the verb reír apparently does not exist.

Comment: You sure you gave the right link? The page says: ` The verb entered does not match any possible conjugation table.`

Comment: @Thomas apologies I copied the link incorrectly, have since updated

Comment: @baduker apologies I copied the link incorrectly, have since updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-spanish-verb-reír.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
conjugations = soup.find_all('div', class_='blue-box-wrap')

for form in conjugations:
    print(form.find("p").getText().upper() if form.find("p") else "N/A")
    for row in form.find_all("li"):
        print(row.getText())
    print("-" * 80)
```

Output:

```
PRESENTE
yo río
tú ríes
él/ella/Ud. ríe
nosotros reímos
vosotros reís
ellos/ellas/Uds. ríen
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUTURO
yo reiré
tú reirás
él/ella/Ud. reirá
nosotros reiremos
vosotros reiréis
ellos/ellas/Uds. reirán
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and so on...
```

As for the English words, these are generated dynamically and `BeautifulSoup` won't see them.